# Package Inheritence tree viewer Plug in for eclipse or App

Tags: java, eclipse, hierarchy

I would like to ask if someone knows  any plug in for eclipse or standalone application where i can provide a number of classes and it will graphically represent the inheritance tree (or even the client relations) . Or i do not know if this is done somehow in eclipse without the use of external tools.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the Hierarchy for a given type by pressing F4 or selecting "Open Type Hierarchy" in the menu...just for one class at a time though.